# What does the k parameter do in the sort function (Linux Bash Scripting)?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

From Linux manual:
sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type.

I have no idea what that means but I saw it being used like this:

```
cut -f 2 *ptt | tail -n +4 | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1 -rn
```

And then again like this:

```
ls -1 *\.flv | sort -n -k1.2
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> KEYDEF is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position, where F is a field number and C a character position in the field; both are origin
>          1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end.  If neither -t nor -b is in effect, characters in a field are counted from  the  beginning  of
>          the  preceding  whitespace.  OPTS is one or more single-letter ordering options [bdfgiMhnRrV], which override global ordering options for that key.
>          If no key is given, use the entire line as the key.

An example input file:

```
123 233
214 176 
341 325
```

sort on the first field:

```
sort -t' ' -k1 input
```

*Gives:*

```
123 233
214 176
341 325
```

The second field:

```
sort -t' ' -k2 input
```

*Gives:*

```
214 176
123 233
341 325
```

Second and third digits of the first field:

```
sort -t' ' -k1.2 input
```

*Gives:*

```
214 176
123 233
341 325
```

Last digit of the second field:

```
sort -t' ' -k2.3 input
```

*Gives:*

```
123 233
341 325
214 176
```

Comment: it might we worth clarifying that the OPTS are the sort command's "-" options e.g. `sort 
 -k8rn,8` is equivalent to `sort -r -n -k8,8`.  it allows you to sort each key in a different way rather than globally for the entire sort command (it took me ages before i realised)

Answer (score 10):

In less words than the manual page: it specifies what "column" the file is sorted by. If the column number contains a period, the value past the period is used as an offset within the field. For instance, `-k1.2` sorts by the second character of the first column.

Columns are normally delimited by tab characters, but you can change that with `-t`. For instance, `-t,` would use columns delimited by commas (e.g, a CSV file).

Comment: The default (in coreutils 8.22 at least) is to split columns based on *whitespace*, not tabs.